# Distance between several latlng with Google maps API

Tags: javascript, python, django, postgresql, google-maps-api-3

If I have stored in my DB several latlng points, and I want to compare those points with my actual latlng position( giving me the distance between each latlng points with my actual latlng), how would that be posible with google maps API? or it's something that it would be easier using my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use your database for this sort of work, you might want to think about using PostGIS for this. With PostGIS installed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

SELECT ST_Distance( 
    ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(115.764286 -31.746416)'), 
    ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(151.036606 -33.906896)')
);
```

Produces:

```
   st_distance    
------------------
 3295294.42439749
(1 row)
```

Compared to Google Maps output, [which thinks it's about 3700 km (walking, not crow-flies)](https://maps.google.com.au/maps?saddr=-31.746416,115.764286&daddr=-33.906896,151.036606&hl=en&ll=-33.063924,133.417969&spn=25.726217,53.569336&sll=-33.086271,133.400092&sspn=25.715807,53.569336&geocode=FZCWG_4dPmzmBg%3BFTCf-v0dvqIACQ&t=h&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&z=5).

So that seems about right, distance wise.

Note that this is spheroid distance, i.e over the earth's surface, not point-to-point through it.

Watch out for the co-ordinate order in PostGIS vs Google Maps.

To learn more about PostGIS:

- [Introduction to PostGIS](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/)
- [Introduction to PostGIS - Geography](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html)
- [PostGIS.net](http://postgis.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Computing the distance between two points on a sphere requires the use of the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), which requires a pretty solid understanding of trigonometry.

The easier way would be to leverage the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) which has the handy function `computeDistanceBetween` in the `google.maps.geometry.spherical` namespace.

Here's some sample code for using `computeDistanceBetween`:

```
var home = ['London', new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.1167)];

var pts = [
        ['Prague', new google.maps.LatLng(50.08, 14.43)],
        ['Paris', new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.3522219000000177)],
        ['Berlin', new google.maps.LatLng(52.5200065999, 13.404953999999975)]
];

// provide a shortcut for the distance function
var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween;

pts.forEach(function(pt){
    var d = dist(home[1], pt[1])/1000;
    // d is now the distance (in km) between the home coordinate and the point
});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aJTK2/5/

Comment: Thanks! @ethan brown, I think this is going to help me, What I'm trying to do is, e.g. I'm a user and I'm saving with the google maps API a route from my home to my university, so another user that live nearby from the origin or any waypoints of the route could recive a recommendation of this existing route, that's why I want to compare my actual latlng with all the others stored in my DB, but maybe I need to define a radius to make things faster?

Comment: Yes, performance is going to be an issue...determining the distance between two points on a sphere is computationally expensive.  One way is to use squares instead of radii for kind of a coarse filtering, then do the spherical computations only on points that fall inside the square.

Comment: Yes, that's what a I thought, thank you very much :)

Comment: I have a confusion now, how can I use the squares?, do you have a code example?

Comment: That's a pretty big question.  Basically you just treat latitude & longitude like cartesian coordinates (instead of spherical ones) and use the approximation of 1°~=111 km.  So, for example, if you wanted to find all coordinates within about 50 km of a given point, you would just do a numeric comparison to see if it was within a quarter of a degree in any direction.  Give it a try, and ask another SO question if you can't get it to work.